# Passing array values for loop TWIG+symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Before I go on with my code, I apologize in advance. I am just starting to learn twig and symfony.

Ok, so I have a controller that renders a simple html.twig. Where I am stuck is at the syntax of passing values in the for loop. Let me show you what I have:

Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/mine.html.twig', array(
        'user_name' => 'trolol',
        'one_li' => 'Learn Symfony',
        'two_li' => 'Learn Controller',
        'three_li' => 'Learn Twig',
        'four_li' => 'Eat',
        'nav' => array(
            '1':'11',
            '2':'22'
        )
    );
};
}
```

Twig:

```
<p>Welcome <h2>{{ user_name }}</h2></p>
    <p> To Do:
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li>{{ one_li }}</li>
        <li>{{ two_li }}</li>
        <li>{{ three_li }}</li>
        <li>{{ four_li }}</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul id="nav">
        {% for link,text in nav %}
            <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

If I remove the loop part of the twig and controller, it works as expected. So now, I am stuck on figuring out the syntax for what I am trying to do. Any help on how I would accomplish what I am failing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
'nav' => array(
            '1':'11',
            '2':'22'
        )
```

You must use this:

```
'nav' => array(
            '1' => '11',
            '2' => '22'
        )
```

Your Twig code seems okay. You just can't define arrays in PHP the way you did.

EDIT: Looks like you have some typos. Try with this code:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/mine.html.twig', array(
            'user_name' => 'trolol',
            'one_li' => 'Learn Symfony',
            'two_li' => 'Learn Controller',
            'three_li' => 'Learn Twig',
            'four_li' => 'Eat',
            'nav' => array('1' => '11', '2' =>'22')
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I get CRITICAL - Fatal Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 25 /// if I delete the ; I get an error unexpected } etc etc.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it

Comment: Oh wow. I was missing one closing ) there. Thank you very much. One last question since we are on the subject. If I wanted to pass a one more, so something like this

    <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ text }} {{ third }}</a></li>


Would the syntax be?
    'nav' => array(
                '1' => '11' => '111',
                '2' => '22' => '222'
            ))

Comment: No, you can't define it like that. You should add a dimension to array: 'nav' => array('1' => array('11', '111'), '2' => array('2' => array('22', '222'))) and you should change Twig code as well. It would get harder. If you are gonna print them the way you described, "text" followed by "third" whith a blank space in the middle you could define the array this way 'nav' => array('1' => '11 111' , '2' => '22 222'). They could be variables of course.